# Writing in parallel to a bitset (array of an array) on a GPU

Tags: algorithm, cuda

Here's a GPU algorithms question relevant to a problem I'm trying to speed up:

Let's suppose I conceptually have a data field like the following, where 512 is the number of threads in the block:

```
bool is_a_foo[131072][512];
```

The `bool`s in this structure represent whether data elsewhere (which happens to have similar dimensions... but that's irrelevant) is a `foo`.  For simplicity, let's assume I'm just running on one GPU block, with each thread ripping through (in lock step via a `__syncwarp()`... but please don't let that be too distracting, as in practice I'm doing something more sensical) locations `0`->`131071`. In other words, each thread's code looks something like the following:

```
// assume is_a_foo is initialized earlier to 0's by some sort of memset call
// assume that the values for is_a_foo can go from false->true but never from true->false
for (int i = 0; i < 131072; ++i) {
    if (something_kind_of_expensive_but_not_the_bottleneck()) {
        is_a_foo[ i ][thread] = true;
    }
}
```

With each `bool` represented as 8 bits, no data is lost.  However, let's suppose that I'd like to tighten up the memory/cache footprint and bandwidth consumption.  We could instead represent the above data structure as:

```
unsigned int is_a_foo[131072][512 / (sizeof(unsigned int) * 8)];
```

And we can perform bit arithmetic to set the particular bit of interest to 1.

The problem is that without any special handling, the writes to `is_a_foo` will smash each other, and not every bit that should be set to a 1 will necessarily be set to a 1.

In the case that we're willing to do something special, we can use `atomicCAS` to ensure that no writes are lost.  Unfortunately, this seems kind of expensive.  Indeed, in my application, where a kernel launch takes about 30 milliseconds, the kernel execution time increases by ~33%.  It's currently unclear whether the additional time is due to the atomic op or the extra instructions, but I suspect it's the atomic op.

One thing that would mitigate the damage is if I were able to operate on `unsigned char`s instead of `unsigned int`s.  Unfortunately, CUDA provides no such interface.  And, when I operate on `unsigned short`s, I get a compiler error about the function not being available for `unsigned short`s (details available upon request).

All this is to ask, *are there any algorithms/data structures that are a good fit for this type of operation on a GPU*?

Comment: Generally cross-posting is bad, but the stackoverflow format tends to bring more readers, so I'm posting it here too.  OP is at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048567/cuda-programming-and-performance/-gpu-algorithms-writing-in-parallel-to-a-bitset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered packing your bits in a different way? If consecutive bits in an int belonged to the *first* component of your 2D array, rather than the second, you would benefit from the lower memory footprint, while avoiding false sharing.

Consider the structure:

```
static constexpr bits = sizeof(unsigned int) * 8;

class IsAFoo {
  private:
    static constexpr size = 131072/bits;
    unsigned int data[size][512];
  public:
    __host__ __device__ void set(int i, int thread, bool value) {
      unsigned int bit = 1u << (i%bits);
      if (value)
        data[i/bits][thread] |= bit;
      else
        data[i/bits][thread] &= ~(bit);
    }
    __host__ __device__ bool get(int i, int thread) {
      return bool(data[i/bits][thread] & (1u << (i%bits));
    }
}

__device__ IsAFoo is_a_foo;
```

... and then the rest of your algorithm will work as before - you would just need to use the above `set` and `get` functions. This obviously assumes that anywhere else in your program you don't try to change the array using a different pattern, like `set(threadIdx.x, commonValue)`.

What is more, if the optimizer is clever, or with some manual tweaks on your side, you could significantly reduce the overall number of operations on the main memory. Something like:

```
unsigned int tmpFlags = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 131072; ++i) {
    if (something_kind_of_expensive_but_not_the_bottleneck()) {
        tmpFlags |= 1u << (i % bits)
    }
    if (i % bits == bits - 1) {
        is_a_foo.setBulk(i, threadIdx.x, tmpFlags)
        tmpFlags = 0;
    }
}
```

(assuming `setBulk` is given in the `IsAFoo` class). This will reduce the overall number of global memory operations by a factor of 32, at a cost of a single additional live register and a few arithmetic operations.

Comment: wow, what a clever idea @CygnusX1 !  That definitely reduces my memory footprint, which is at least half of what I'm trying to achieve.  Was also kind of looking forward to relieving some memory bandwidth pressure too, but I'll have to try what you suggested first.

Comment: The slowdown with this method isn't easily observed -- I suspect the performance is very close to negligible or the same, which is great.  I want to test the `ballot` function before accepting this answer, but things are looking good so far.

Comment: Slowdown may different depending on how you later *use* the array. If it is just one read in between some heavy computation it won't matter. But if the core of your algorithm reads this array extensively...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any CUDA-capable GPU with a warp size of 512, so I'm assuming you meant to write block size and `__syncthreads()` rather than warp size and `__syncwarp()` (warp size is 32 on every single CUDA architecture in existence so far). I may also direct your attention to the fact that there exists an [`atomicOr()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicor) function.

To minimize the number of atomics (or global memory traffic in general), a typical approach would be to perform a [parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) within your block (using shared memory) to build up the result for the entire block and then only in the end use a bunch of threads to move the result out to global memory. In general, I can highly recommend to have a look at [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/) for a library that provides CUDA implementations of all sorts of parallel programming primitives such as reductions. In your particular case, however, threads within the same warp can simply perform the reduction in question using the [`__ballot()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) warp vote function (which maps to a single instruction). Since the numbers work out in your case such that the result is exactly one 32-Bit bitmask per warp (32 threads), you can just do a `__ballot()` and then have one (e.g., the first) thread of each warp write the result. If I understand your problem correctly, you won't even need atomics then, as the result seems to be one bitmask per warp per block, which means no concurrent access to the same location as soon as you have only one thread accessing global memory per warp…

Comment: Good point about my lack of clarity on what I meant by 512.  I've tried to clean it up.

AFAIK, I'm not actually trying to do any reduction, in the classic sense -- maybe I've got the wrong definition of reduction.  That being said, the `__ballot()` function looks like it might be exactly what I'm looking for.  Will look more into that. Thanks @michaelkenzel!